# Windows Phone deep links are not properly encoded

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, deep-linking

Let's assume I have a Windows Phone app capable of [handling deep links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) with "my-app:" moniker. Given the following sample link:

> my-app://do/stuff/?artist=Macklemore%20%26%20Ryan%20Lewis&test=1

We can visible see two query string params, `artist = "Macklemore & Ryan Lewis"` and `test = "1"`.

If I create a webpage with that link on it and open the page inside Internet Explorer in the phone, this is what gets to the app UriMapper:

> /Protocol?encodedLaunchUri=my-app%3A%2F%2Fdo%2Fstuff%2F%3Fartist%3DMacklemore%20%26%20Ryan%20Lewis%26test%3D1

So, it seems that none of the `%` encoded values got re-encoded, but yet it encoded the `&` just before the `test` parameter…

This seems to me like a platform bug, as we won’t be able to distinguish the & chars we get on the UriMapper!

So the question is if anyone know a way of using encoded ampersands (%26) in a windows phone deep link?

Comment: Indeed, that's troublesome. Maybe you can first HTML-encode your `artist` parameter (so that ampersands are replaced by `&amp;`) then HTML-decode the URL in your Windows Phone app.

Comment: Sure, I could do that or even replace with some other char, but in the end I'm just bypassing the true issue with the way Windows Phone handles deep links... in the end, what I have is to get a set of rules for deep links and tell users to HtmlEncode params before creating the url... :\

Comment: Well yes but I don't see what else you can do. As far as I know, you have no control whichever over how Windows Phone encodes the URL. There's only two parts you can act on: the URL you provide, and the way you decode the URL. You've already concluded, rightfully so, that you can't distinguish the encoded ampersands from the %26 that were already in the URL (except if you implement some smart pattern-detection logic, to detect `&xxxx=`). So the only way left is changing the deep-link URL

Comment: Though... Maybe there's a way to retrieve the URL without using the UriMapper? I'm going to peek around the API a bit, especially the objects like `Deployment` or `Application`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the issue might be too low level to access with any of the public APIs.

As a starting point, I figured what we do have at our disposal (and that won't require changes on the user side), which is the ability to detect where the `&` signs are. From that we can determine if the `&` is part of a value or a query string delimiter. If the latter, we replace it with a random character and split on that character.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"(\b&.*?)=");
```

The above regex matches only the `&` that is followed by `=` (so it would match `&test=` below but not `Macklemore & Ryan Lewis`).

We then replace all instances of `&` that are matched by the above regex with a random character that won't be used elsewhere. For this example, I just used `|`.

```
string mapperInput = @"Protocol?encodedLaunchUri=my-app://do/stuff/?artist=Macklemore & Ryan Lewis&test=1";

string final = rx.Replace(mapperInput, 
                       new MatchEvaluator(
                       new Func<Match, string>(x =>  x.Value.Replace('&', '|'))
                       ));
```

We then take that result and put it in a collection.

```
//skip 2 because the first two matches include the protocol section
var values = final.Split(new char[] { '?', '|' }).Skip(2).ToArray();
```

The `values` array now contains two elements (which can be iterated and placed into a Dictionary to have `Key-Value` access)

```
artist=Macklemore & Ryan Lewis
test=1
```

This would have to be tested with various inputs that include characters but from a quick test, it seemed to work fine.

Comment: And here comes the smart pattern-detection logic, on a plate. Nicely done :)

Comment: Thanks :) Will need further testing but tried it with multiple values and seems to work fine. Going to try and see what could be causing the issue so that hopefully it can be fixed in a future update. An improvement to the above is to detect `&` that *isn't* a delimiter so that it can be replaced and the standard `QueryString` methods can be used to split.

Comment: Dug as far as I could. Put a breakpoint in the UriMapper, call the quickwatch window, then execute `Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.ApplicationHost.Current.Uri`. The result is an already-encoded URL. Any further than that and we step into native code.

Comment: @KooKiz - I had a feeling that might be the case. I tried to recreate the output it's giving using `HttpUtility` encode/decode methods and `Uri` Escape string methods but couldn't get a combination that outputs what Pedro is seeing. Maybe the native implementation has a bug, or, is used in conjunction with the managed one causing this issue.